# Usage and origin of the expression "bacon collar"?

Tags: single-word-requests, history

Some polo-shirts suffer from the ***bacon collar*** syndrome. That is, the edges of a shirt collar begin to curl up after several washes and never regain that original, crisp look.

[image: Polo shirt collar]

*Limp*, *flaccid*, *floppy* and *misshapen* also describe this affliction, but I'm thinking there must be a more technical term.

What is this defect called in the shirt-making trade?

A user has kindly pointed out that my question is perhaps not suited for this forum. So... I'm also curious about the term *bacon collar*.

Whose brainchild was it, and when did it make its first appearance in print?

Comment: I think you need to ask this in a clothing forum, it's too domain specific for a general English language forum.

Comment: @MaxWilliams thanks for the tip. Is that any better?

Comment: `Limp, flaccid` I disagree with these terms (from a general English perspective) as they would imply a _lack_ of strength, whereas the bacon collar is actually fighting gravity **more** than it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Bacon collar](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=bacon%20collar)***,  also ***bacon neck***:

There is no reference  available  apart from a [U.D.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bacon%20Neck) post from 2010. The expression most likely has been used before:

> - When a person's collar on their shirt ripples simulating ***the shape of cooked bacon.***
>
>   - Hey, see that guy two rows next to us? He has bacon neck.

[image]

According  to this  [site](http://www.undershirtguy.com/hanes-launches-new-michael-jordan-undershirt-bacon-neck-television-commercial/) the expression was coined in a 2010  commercial with Micheal Jordan.

> - In the commercials, ***they’ve coined and are using the new term “bacon neck” as a way to describe a worn out, frayed, and sagging undershirt collar.***  I think it’s pretty ingenious of them to create a funny phrase that describes sagging undershirt collars. Now, when I see guys wearing an undershirt with a worn out collar, I’ll probably think the guy’s got “bacon neck” now.

Comment: The posted definition refers to an undershirt collar, which is a different style than a polo shirt's collar.  This indicates that "bacon collar" does not apply to the question that was asked. Michael Jordan endorses Hanes, which is known more for undergarments than for casual wear (though they have produced both.)

Comment: @jejorda2 - how long do you think it took before the expression was applied to polo and shirts collars?

Comment: I don't have any evidence that it has (or hasn't) been applied to other styles. Your answer could be improved by citing a quote that clearly applies to something that's not an undershirt.

Comment: @jejorda2 - if you look at the pictures that appear clicking on the first link, both underwear,  polo and shirts will appear. The term, probably coined for that commercial, is applied to collars which show the "bacon effect".

Comment: So take one of the links and cite the material in the answer in case it the link changes later.  It will be more useful to future readers that way.